Show a fake file path for mp3s
I've seen a lot of posts here about creating fake paths with htaccess, but nothing seems to fit exactly what I want.
Part 1: I have a site that sells my own compositions. I'm happy for them to be streamed and downloaded through the website, but I want to deny people pasting in the direct url to the file and downloading it for free. ATM the file path can be easily found either by looking at the page code or in some pages, simply by hovering over the play button!
So what I want to try is, instead of showing this:
mydomain/songs/file1.mp3
Show it as;
mydomain/fakedirectory/file1.mp3
Or even better;
mydomain/fakedirectory/fakefilenameXYZ.mp3
Part 2: And at the same time, if they do guess the real path (songs/file1.mp3) and paste that in their browser, then deny access to the file and show a 404 - without impeding playing of the mp3 and showing the images.
For Part 2, I tried deny from all, but it also hid all images at the front end and stopped the mp3s from playing.
Part 1. I'm not sure where to start.
PS: Suggest someone with sufficient points create a tag called #fakepath. I couldn't do it.

What would faking the path achieve? You'd still need to resolve a request to a real file in order for it to stream. If you want access controls, you'll need some sort of authorisation overlay.

How do you currently handle access/authorization on your site? Are you using PHP?

This might help but it's far from comprehensive since referrers can be easily faked or absent due to client-side security controls ~ Allow/deny image hotlinking with .htaccess

What you want to do is stop exposing your raw files via http at all. Once you publish the files that way you have no control any more, regardless of the "path" you chose for that. instead you want to implement something like a router logic, maybe some simple php script, that handles authentification and authorization and only hands out the content of those files once the requirements are fulfilled. That way you can hold the files in a server side location that is not directly accessible via a http request.

See How to serve videos in a website somewhat securely and How to protect a video streaming url by hiding or masking it and How to password protect streaming videos with php.
